# What programming languages target J2ME?

Tags: compiler-construction, java-me, jvm, interpreter, nokia

I recently received a Nokia 5000 phone. Now I want to write software for it. Trouble is, I don't know Java.

Now I've heard of other languages which supposedly make possible development without recourse to Java, languages like [CellularBASIC](http://cellbasic.sourceforge.net/index.php/) (which looks a bit like QBASIC) and [Hecl](http://www.hecl.org/) (which seems to be based on Tcl).

Are these the only ones? Links, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I wrote Hecl, by the way, so ask away if you have questions about it)

I think there is a version of Forth floating around, and maybe an attempt at Lua.

J2ME is still a fairly limited environment though, so you're not going to get 'kitchen sink' languages unless they compile down to Java bytecodes.  Symbian phones support some sort of Python, but that's not J2ME.

Comment: Hecl looks good if only because I've always liked Tcl. I had a look at the HeclBuilder site and am optimistic that Hecl will take me where I want to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to make an effort to learn a new language anyways, you should definitely consider Java. Not only will it help you in your current goal, but in today's market, it is a valuable skill to have.

If the vastness of the language intimidates you then you can consider learning ActionScript which is a close cousin of JavaScript. It's simple and has a C-like syntax, ships with a powerful library and costs nothing to begin with. Making stuff in ActionScript is fun.

But my first preference would still be learning Java.

Answer (score 1):

The [Nokia 5000](http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/5000/) supports applications in J2ME and [Flash Lite](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashlite/). All other languages should be implemented on top of these (mainly on J2ME). These implementations will definitely be slow and probably very restricted, as J2ME is itself slow and a cut-down version of full Java.

However you shouldn't be intimidating by Java. Download [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) and optionally the SDK from Nokia to get you started. If you have experience in any other object-oriented language, you should be able to code your first application quickly.